# Extensive library for openGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is there any easy-to-use library for openGL ES on Android using which drawing regular objects like cylinder, torus, sphere, cube etc. rotating, moving them and detecting touch events becomes easy. I used GLUT GLFrame etc for doing this on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good experiences with jPCT-AE http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/
Reasonably good framework with OK documentation. They do also support object picking

Comment: Very cool Ill have to check that one out myself. Whats the object picking accuracy like when there's a high volume of objects onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Mind3d is one

http://code.google.com/p/min3d/

Im not sure if its exactly what your looking for but it has a decent number of users and a wiki thats not to bad

Comment: If you want to touch the model you do wise to stay away from min3d until they fix object picking. It is still on their todo list. http://code.google.com/p/min3d/wiki/todos

Comment: I just took a look at the list and Im not sure if its current because you can now import different 3d file formats so its possible theyve updated the object picking but I have no idea as I havent used it myself for a while.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk/android Here are libraruie with augmented reality but also with open gl that helps you to create 3d objects and others